# How to increase the gutter width in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Idea 14.1.3 on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3. Often, while debugging, I want to introduce a break point by clicking on the left margin (called the 'gutter' in Intellij). The problem is that on many lines, there is no space to click. No matter how I try, the click happens on an icon already present ... which is not what I want to do. Attached a screenshot to show this

> [image: intellij screenshot]

How can I increase the gutter width so that there is some empty space even where the little green override symbols are present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem there is a way to configure the gutter size, it just resizes dynamically. I'd suggest raising an issue in the [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

As a workaround you can set a breakpoint on any line via the editor window. Set the caret on the line to stop at, and press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> (on a Mac).

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be fixed in some future release of IntelliJ:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137353#tab=History